# Why did Hugh Jackman leave the X-Men franchise?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, casting

Why is Logan is the last movie of this franchise starring Hugh Jackman?

Is there any chance of him appearing in a future X-Men movie, or even a guest appearance?

Comment: Why Jackman is leaving the franchise is not difficult to find online.  A simple Google search for "[hugh jackman leaving xmen](https://www.google.ca/search?q=hugh+jackman+leaving+xmen&rlz=1C1NHXL_enCA691CA691&oq=hugh+jackman+leaving+xmen&aqs=chrome..69i57.5774j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" gives plenty of articles on the subject.  We do encourage people to at least *try* to research a subject before asking.  Whether or not he'll make another cameo later on is speculation at this point.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Plus, there is no guarantee that he has left the role. This is **opinion-based** and almost otally speculative. VTC

Answer (score 3):

Two (or three reasons):

Wolverine's story is pretty much done - as is the X-men. Good chance is that the next X-men movies will be a reboot, or part of other continuities currently underway.

Jackman is also getting tired of the role (not necessarily fed up, but he's done 8 or 9 movies as Wolverine, now).

https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/www.gamespot.com/amp-articles/hugh-jackman-on-why-hes-retiring-as-wolverine/1100-6448379/

Finally, Jackman is getting older. The role is physically demanding. One aspect of the last movie was that Wolverine is finally succumbing to aging - partly to ease up on the physical demand on Jackman to shape up for the role.

Comment: I remember watching an interview where he said he thought it was going to be a 2 or 3 movie deal and never expected to play the character for 15 years.

Comment: I remember reading an interview where he said his wife hates when he plays Wolverine because he has to diet and work out to get his body perfect and he gets really cranky...lol.

Comment: @rtaft, explains why Logan is so cranky....

Answer (score 3):

### Because "it felt like the right time".

Jackman explained this in [an interview on the Dr. oz show in 2015](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/05/08/hugh-jackman-wolverine_n_7241786.html).

> It just felt like it was the right time to do it. And let's be honest, 17 years. I never thought in a million years it would last, so I'm so grateful to the fans for the opportunity of playing it. ... I kind of have in my head what we're going to do in this last one. It just feels like this is the perfect way to go out.

Before the release of *Logan*, he had mentioned that [he would have considered continuing if he could have crossed over with the Avengers.](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/hugh-jackman-logan-wolverine-3-x-men-the-avengers-marvel-interview-a7598996.html)

> If [an Avengers-crossover] was on the table when I made my decision, it certainly would have made me pause. That’s for sure. Because I always love the idea of him within that dynamic, with the Hulk obviously, with Iron Man but there’s a lot of smarter people with MBAs who can’t figure that out. You never know.”

Whether or not this is still on the table for him is unclear.